# Using of article 'the ' before profession

Tags: articles

I am studying English language. I have read a rule that there must be used article 'a/an' before profession. This rule is written, for example, [this blog post](http://www.davidappleyard.com/english/articles.htm) says, "You'll see that English puts an indefinite article in front of a profession but German doesn’t." But I think that this rule is not working if I mention profession second, third time. For example I think I could say something next:

*Our teacher of english language said that we need to use articles. The teacher <strike>said</strike> talked about differences between two types of articles.*

The question is: is it okay to use 'the' in second mention. And second question: may I say article 'a' before teacher in the second sentence from example.

Comment: Don't confuse general guidelines with hard-and-fast rules.

Comment: Children are particularly liable to omit the article in contexts like *Teacher told us to be quite,* or *When I was sick, Nurse stayed in my bedroom all night.* But it's essentially a *childish* usage that they grow out of, except in contexts where the speaker is using the [professional] profession/role as a *term of address* (as in, for example, *Can I take my lunch break now, **Boss**?*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same blog post you mention says:

> The definite article *the* is used in front of **any noun the listener or reader already knows about**.

So, when you say:

> Our teacher said that we need to use articles.

we now know about the teacher. Therefore:

> The teacher talked about differences between two types of articles.

Is the natural way to say it, because the teacher was mentioned in the previous sentence. You wouldn’t use *a* instead of *the*, because you are talking about the teacher you already mentioned.

You could word something this way, though:

> **A** teacher said that we need to use articles. **That** teacher talked about differences between two types of articles.

---

By the way, the “rule” you initially cited is trying to say that you don’t use the word *teacher* without any kind of modifier. In other words, you would **NOT** say this:

> Teacher said that we need to use articles. Teacher talked about differences between two types of articles. `(incorrect)`

We don’t generally begin sentences with words like *teacher, carpenter, doctor,* or *policewoman*. Instead, we use article, possessive pronouns, or some other determiner:

> **Our** teacher said...
>   **A** carpenter told me...
>   **My** doctor wants...
>   **That** policewoman saw...